# How to replace all {!XXX} from string?

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have string with multiple `{!XXX}` phrases. For example:

```
String sTemp = 'Kumar gaurav {!str1} is just {!str2}, adasdas {!str3}';
```

I need to replace all `{!str}` values with corresponding `str`, How to build replace all `{!str}` to `str` ?

Comment: What are you replacing those strings with? Do you know before hand how many replacements you need to do? Do you have the corresponding strings for each of those? Please provide more info, the current question is unclear and most likely will be closed by the community.

Comment: i have found below method but it replace only one phrase :

public String mergeString(String eixstingString){
  String templateString = eixstingString.substring(eixstingString.indexOf('{'), eixstingString.indexOf('}') + 1); 
  String fieldName = eixstingString.substring(eixstingString.indexOf('.') + 1, eixstingString.indexOf('}')); 
  return eixstingString.replace(templateString, 'myvalue');
}

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can try using replaceall method by passing a regular expression to the method.

Comment: -1 `replaceAll` is quite error prone and not optimal. other answer with `String.format` is much cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

You can use [`String.format(stringToFormat, formattingArguments)`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_format) to insert an arbitrary number of tokens into an existing `String`.

```
String placeholder = 'Hello {0}, {1} is cool!';
List<String> fillers = new String[]{'Jason','Apex'};
String formatted = String.format(placeholder, fillers);
System.assertEquals('Hello Jason, Apex is cool!', formatted);
```